# Visual Studio thinks everything is a TypeScript resource

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I'm using Cordova to build an app, and I'm trying to get a Windows app to build. Using the Cordova CLI didn't yield any good results, so I tried to build the Visual Studio solution in the platforms/windows folder.

The problem is that it fails building and returns a long list of errors all of which pretty much just say something similar to this:

> **TS6054**    Build: File 'C:/Code/ProjectClosr/Cordova
>   App/platforms/windows/www/Gruntfile.js' has unsupported extension. The
>   only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

Now, turns out that it thinks all of these files are TypeScript files, even though they are just Readme's, JavaScript files, CSS files etc. and it does that because for some reason all of those files in their properties have 'Package Action' set to **TypeScriptCompile**. Now, I didn't create this solution obviously, it was autogenerated by Cordova, but I need a way to fix this by somehow setting the 'Package Action' property for all of them back to their real values, instead of everything being a TypeScript resource.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you have a **TypeScript** file somewhere inside the folder you are adding using the **wildcard**. Don't know why but MSVS changes **Content** type to **TypeScriptCompile** for the whole bunch of the files found by the wildcard you provide inside the folder.

In my case I had `angular-ui-router.d.ts` file inside `www\lib\angular-ui-router\api`.

Resolved by adding **Exclude** directive in CordovaApp.projitems file:

```
<Content Include="www\**" Exclude="**\*.ts" />
```

Also note that **$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)** should be removed from the path since it magically breaks the trick.

Comment: I banged my head for days because of this. You're a genius!

Comment: This just worked for me while building cordova app for windows platform. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> and it does that because for some reason all of those files in their properties have 'Package Action' set to TypeScriptCompile.

Just remove the `<TypeScriptCompile ...` keys from the solution by raw editing it. They are probably also already present as `<Content ...` which is what you need.

Comment: Well, I tried finding any places with TypeScriptCompile, and the only file that had it was CordovaApp.projitems, instead of the solution file and the line looked like this - <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)www\**" />. After changing it and reloading the solution, though, it didn't seem to work and when saving the solution it even reverted that line back.

Comment: It also looks like I can't change the Package Action of each file manually - it immediately reverts back to TypeScriptCompile.

Comment: Removing the `<TypeScriptCompile>` nodes fixes the issue but also drops the files from the project, so you have to re-add them manually as existing items and then VS adds them correctly without flagging them as TS.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) you should have set **"allowJs": true** inside your **tsconfig.json** to allow .js extension.

Hope this help!

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "./scripts/",
    "allowJs": true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pavel Kozlov's solution worked wonderfully for me.

If you are using Cordova, you can use the following script to have it done automatically:

`./reset_windows.sh`

```
cordova platform rm windows
cordova platform add windows
sed -i '9s/.*/        <Content Include="www\\**" Exclude="**\\*.ts" \/>/' platforms/windows/CordovaApp.projitems
```

Make sure the old line you want to replace is actually line 9 as the `9s` says at the beginning of the command.